# caffe2 Tensor<CUDAContext> assignment, construction or copy

Tags: c++, opencv, caffe2

This is a long shot, if you think the question is too localized, please do vote to close. I have searched on the [caffe2 github](https://github.com/caffe2/caffe2) repository, opened [an issue](https://github.com/caffe2/caffe2/issues/1004) asking the same question, opened another issue at the [caffe2_ccp_tutorials](https://github.com/leonardvandriel/caffe2_cpp_tutorial/issues/7) repository because its author seems to understand it best, read the doxygen documentation on [caffe2::Tensor](https://caffe2.ai/doxygen-c/html/classcaffe2_1_1Tensor.html) and [caffe2::CUDAContext](https://caffe2.ai/doxygen-c/html/classcaffe2_1_1CUDAContext.html), 
and even gone through the caffe2 [source code](https://github.com/caffe2/caffe2/tree/master/caffe2/core), and in specific the `tensor.h`, `context_gpu.h` and `context_gpu.cc`.

I understand that currently **caffe2 does not allow copying device memory to a tensor**. I am willing to expand the library and do a pull request in order to achieve this. My reason behind this is that I do all image pre-processing using `cv::cuda::*` methods which operate on device memory, and as such I think it is clearly a problem doing the pre-processing on the gpu, only to download the result back on the host, and then have it re-uploaded to the network from host to device.

Looking at the constructors of `Tensor<Context>` I can see that maybe only

```
template<class SrcContext , class ContextForCopy > 
Tensor (const Tensor< SrcContext > &src, ContextForCopy *context)
```

might achieve what I want, but I have no idea how to set the `<ContextForCopy>` and then use it for construction.

Furthermore, I see that I can construct the Tensor with the correct dimensions, and then *maybe* using

```
template <typename T>
T* mutable_data()
```

I can assign/copy the data.
The data itself is stored in `std::vector<cv::cuda::GpuMat`, so I will have to iterate it, and then use either [`cuda::PtrStepSz` or `cuda::PtrStep`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/cuda/doc/data_structures.html) to access the underlying device allocated data.
That is the same data that I need to copy/assign into the `caffe2::Tensor<CUDAContext>`.

I've been trying to find out how internally the `Tensor<CPUContext>` is copied to `Tensor<CUDAContext>` since I've seen examples of it, but I can't figure it out, although I think the method used is [`CopyFrom`](https://github.com/caffe2/caffe2/blob/14480d63e3f5cf83e58317499d4de9515e92a7e0/caffe2/core/tensor.h#L105). The usual examples as already mentioned, copy from CPU to GPU:

```
TensorCPU tensor_cpu(...);
TensorCUDA tensor_cuda = workspace.CreateBlob("input")->GetMutable<TensorCUDA>();
tensor_cuda->ResizeLike(tensor_cpu);
tensor_cuda->ShareData(tensor_cpu);
```

I am quite suprised nobody has run into this task yet, and a brief search yields only one [open issue](https://github.com/caffe2/caffe2/issues/694) where the author (@peterneher) is asking the same thing more or less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to figure this out.
The simplest way is to tell OpenCV **which** memory location to use.
This can be done by using the [7th and 8th overload of the `cv::cuda::GpuMat` constructor](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d0/d60/classcv_1_1cuda_1_1GpuMat.html#ab7210166f4bd124855b520b3dde28fb1) shown below:

```
cv::cuda::GpuMat::GpuMat(int    rows,
                         int    cols,
                         int    type,
                         void *     data,
                         size_t     step = Mat::AUTO_STEP 
                        )       

cv::cuda::GpuMat::GpuMat(Size   size,
                         int    type,
                         void *     data,
                         size_t     step = Mat::AUTO_STEP 
                        )
```

Doing so implies that the `caffe2::TensorCUDA` has been declared and **allocated** beforehand:

```
std::vector<caffe2::TIndex> dims({1, 3, 224, 224});
caffe2::TensorCUDA tensor;
auto ptr = tensor.mutable_data<float>();
cv::cuda::GpuMat matrix(224, 224, CV_32F, ptr);
```

For example, processing a 3 channel BGR float matrix using `cv::cuda::split`:

```
cv::cuda::GpuMat mfloat;
// TODO: put your BGR float data in `mfloat`
auto ptr = tensor.mutable_data<float>();
size_t width = mfloat.cols * mfloat.rows;
std::vector<cv::cuda::GpuMat> input_channels {
    cv::cuda::GpuMat(mfloat.rows, mfloat.cols, CV_32F, &ptr[0]),
    cv::cuda::GpuMat(mfloat.rows, mfloat.cols, CV_32F, &ptr[width]),
    cv::cuda::GpuMat(mfloat.rows, mfloat.cols, CV_32F, &ptr[width * 2])
};
cv::cuda::split(mfloat, input_channels);
```

Hope this will help anyone dwelling into the C++ side of Caffe2.

**NOTE** that `caffe2::Predictor` won't work with `caffe2::TensorCUDA`, you will have instead to manually propagate the tensor.
For more information on this, [the caffe2_cpp_tutorial mnist.cc](https://github.com/leonardvandriel/caffe2_cpp_tutorial/blob/d5daf4e89b9b1a12979649e783d68f4c821a554f/src/caffe2/binaries/mnist.cc#L380).